# Duplicate json data populating inside RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, api, rest

I built an app which is connected with local server to get the json data and want to print that data inside the recycler view,  but that data is duplicating inside the recycler view. I am not getting the exact error in my program.

```java
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    tBikeName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bike_name);
    tBikePrice=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bike_price);
    bikeList=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.bike_recycler_view);
    bikeList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    adapter=new BikeAdapter(modelList,MainActivity.this);
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/BikeData/bike/bikeList";
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                try {
                    JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(myResponse);
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        BikeModel model=new BikeModel();
                        model.bikeName=jsonObject.getString("bikeName");
                        model.bikePrice=jsonObject.getString("bikePrice");
                        modelList.add(model);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        bikeList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Do share your coding part

Comment: thanks, but how to share this code ?

Comment: could you share your mail to send my code ?

Comment: satyaprakashsasmal966@gmail.com       this is my mail id